# dotnet core package versioning

Tags: git, nuget, .net-core, csproj, semantic-versioning

How can I generate a semantic version number, based on a tag in Git, for a NuGet package (*e.g.* MyCode.0.1.1.nupkg) using the `dotnet` CLI?

[GitInfo](https://www.clarius.org/GitInfo/) is correctly versioning our assemblies but I would like to extend this to versioning our NuGet packages. The following is a snippet from our .csproj :

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>False</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <PackageVersion>$(GitSemVerMajor).$(GitSemVerMinor).$(GitSemVerPatch)$(GitSemVerDashLabel)</PackageVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\..\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs" Link="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="gitinfo" Version="1.1.66" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Note the `GeneratePackageOnBuild`.

What do I have to do to generate those build variables, `$(GitSemVerMajor)`, *etc*. when I call `dotnet build`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Remove the `<PackageVersion>` line from the `.csproj`.
- Add an `InitialTargets` statement to the `Project`:
  `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" InitialTargets="SetVersion">`
- Add an `Import` for the versioning targets file:
  `<Import Project="..\..\Version.targets" />`

The `Version.targets` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
        <Target Name="GitVersion">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <!-- Dummy values allow dotnet restore to progress -->
            <GitBaseVersionMajor>0</GitBaseVersionMajor>
            <GitBaseVersionMinor>1</GitBaseVersionMinor>
            <GitBaseVersionPatch>0</GitBaseVersionPatch>
            <GitCommits>0</GitCommits>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </Target>
    <Target Name="SetVersion" DependsOnTargets="GitVersion">
        <PropertyGroup>
            <!-- CI checkouts may be against a specific commit, not a branch, so add -pr as label -->
            <GitSemVerDashLabel Condition="'$(GitBranch)' == 'undefined'">$(GitSemVerDashLabel)-pr</GitSemVerDashLabel>
            <!-- If there's no label, but we're not at the tip of the base version, add a -pre because this is not the base build -->
            <GitSemVerDashLabel Condition="'$(GitSemVerDashLabel)' == '' And '$(GitCommits)' != '0'">-pre</GitSemVerDashLabel>
            <PackageVersion Condition="'$(GitSemVerDashLabel)' == ''">$(GitBaseVersionMajor).$(GitBaseVersionMinor).$(GitBaseVersionPatch)</PackageVersion>
            <PackageVersion Condition="'$(GitSemVerDashLabel)' != ''">$(GitBaseVersionMajor).$(GitBaseVersionMinor).$(GitBaseVersionPatch)$(GitSemVerDashLabel).$(GitCommits)</PackageVersion>
            <AssemblyVersion>$(GitBaseVersionMajor).$(GitBaseVersionMinor).$(GitBaseVersionPatch)</AssemblyVersion>
        </PropertyGroup>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a CLI tool for .NET Core project versioning [here](https://github.com/TAGC/dotnet-setversion) which I think does what you want.

In your case you would change your `.csproj` file to reference the CLI tool and *omit* the `Version` element:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>False</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>True</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\..\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs" Link="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="gitinfo" Version="1.1.66" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-setversion" Version="*" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

To generate a NuGet package with a particular version, you would just `cd` into the project directory and run `dotnet restore && dotnet setversion <<SOME_VERSION>>`.

This will add a `Version` element to the `.csproj` file, so that any future invocations of `dotnet build`, `dotnet package`, etc. will treat the project as having the specified version. This is particularly useful during CI builds, where you probably want to automatically increment the version number on each run.

For full disclosure, I'm not familiar with GitInfo so I apologise if this isn't applicable in your case. I personally use this tool in conjunction with [GitVersion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion) if there's any similarities between the two.